# Multiple events calling same functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call same javascript function for events like MOUSEOUT and when user press only ENTER key,
multiple events calling same js function

Comment: onblur="javascript:search();" this is the html code i have ,need to change this for enter and onblur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define more than one event by separating them with a space.

```
$('selector').on('keyup mouseout click', function(){
   // will be called commonly
});
```

You can use the above with `bind` also. Also, you could create a separate function and pass it to each handler, but that is overkill, I suppose.

Comment: this could have been a comment as well :)

Comment: As 20k user you should've know better than to answer something like this. Close-vote as dupe instead...

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee no. It couldn't have been, since it *answers* the question/